# SimpleDateFormat parse not honouring timezone

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yy");
    dt.setLenient(false);
    dt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Hong_Kong"));
    Date date = dt.parse("05 14 16");
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

**Output:** `Fri May 13 21:30:00 IST 2016`

If i try to use the output it is switching to one day before instead of the correct day.

Is this expected or an issue with the API?

Comment: I don't know, but you may need to specify the timezone when printing as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected and there is no bug in Java.

Class `Date` does not contain timezone information. A `java.util.Date` is nothing more than wrapper for a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 GMT. It does not remember that the string that it was parsed from contained information about a timezone.

When you display a `Date`, for example by (implicitly) calling `toString()` on it as you are doing here:

```
System.out.println(date);
```

it will be printed in the default timezone of your system, which is IST in your case.

If you want to print it in a certain timezone, then format it using a `SimpleDateFormat` object, setting the desired timezone on the `SimpleDateFormat` object. For example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
df..setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Hong_Kong"));
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```